# IDA Pro sometimes load source files, what's the reason?

Tags: linux, debugging, 64-bit, wine, ida

So I'm trying to debug 'ccom' which was compiled with debug symbols. And so it should perhaps have source file (and lines) information included. I'm debugging it using IDA Pro 'linux_serverx64' (on host) and IDA Pro 6.6 x64 running in Wine (connected to host).

I've set breakpoints on various places inside the program. My problem is that sometimes I can source-debug with IDA Pro and sometimes no.

For example now I've a break-point in 'main'. Like my 2nd try before, when the execution reached it - it allowed source debugging (and so switched to source code automatically) but like right now it wouldn't do it again. What's this?

I had this problem before too and is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that 'clang' (the compiler I used) is storing the source paths as they were being originally passed as arguments. And as I've been using relative patches - this had somehow confused IDA Pro.

You need to pass your source-files to the clang-driver with their absolute path. This solved my problem.